# function returning pointer: max value in c++

Tags: c++

[image]

I made that task but it turn to me a huge number not the maximum

my code is

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int* max(int p[],int n);
   int main (){
     int n;
     int*A=new int;


int *p;

cout<<"enter the value of array";
cin>>n;
p=new int[n];
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
cout<<"enter the element";
cin>>p[n];
}
A=(max(p,n));
cout<<"the maximum is"<<*A;
return 0;

}
int* max(int p[],int n)
{
   int maximum;
   maximum = p[0];
   for(int x=0;x<n;x++)
   {
       if(p[x]>maximum)
       {
           maximum=p[x];
           return &maximum;
       }
   }

   return  &maximum;
}
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you have to use an image instead of pasting the text? Also, your indentation is shot...

Comment: Please format your code properly - currently it's pretty much unreadable.

Comment: If you really used C++, not those terrible raw arrays, you wouldn't have that problem. Also return `int`s by value

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)

Comment: dont use pointer in function return it doesnt seem to be needed.

Comment: so what i can do instead of pointers i a a beginner yet

Comment: You forget to delete your array. Use `vector<int>` instead and it will delete itself for you.

Answer (score 0):

The correct definition of the function can look the following way

```
int * max( int a[], size_t n )
{
    int *maximum = a;

    for ( size_t i = 1; i < n; i++ )
    {
        if ( *maximum < a[i] ) maximum = a + i;
    }

    return maximum;
}
```

Or

```
int * max( int a[], size_t n )
{
    int *maximum = a;

    if ( n != 0 )
    {
        for ( int *p = a + 1; p != a + n; ++p )
        {
            if ( *maximum < *p ) maximum = p;
        }
    }

    return maximum;
}
```

As for your function definition then you are returning pointer to a local variable that in general case will be destroyed after exiting the function. So the program has undefined behaviour.

Take into account that there is no any sense to allocate memory

```
int*A=new int;
```

You will get a memory leak.

Simply define

```
int *A;
```

Also you should know that there is standard algorithm `std::max_element` declared in header `<algorithm>` that performs the same task.

For example you could write

```
#include <algorithm>

//..

A = std::max_element( p, p + n );
```

Comment: your function will return an address so how to appear the value that is at that address on the screen ?

Comment: @ Salma  The same way as you do it yourself: cout<<"the maximum is"<<*A;

Comment: it returns to me a huge number i didn't how to solve this problem

Comment: @Salma  It means you are doing something wrong compared with what I showed.

Comment: @ Salma  Update statement cin>>p[i];